# I have Swift Panel (gaming panel) and i need to enable cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

To enable server monitoring, set up the cron job to run every 10 minutes.

php -q /var/www/html/panel/admin/cron.php

But how exactly do i do this and where should it be ?

Comment: Yeah i did , had to delete it tho for a very valid reason , i do respect the info they gave me.They were 100% right , still tho , i had my reasons to ask that despite knowing what they would say.

Comment: Nahh, thanks tho , time to warm up my chair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a cronjob via `crontab -e`. You have to put it in the right syntax, which would be `*/10 * * * * php -q /var/www/html/panel/admin/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1` (with muted output).

If `vim` is your editor, simply press `i` to enabled the insert mode, go below the comment section, paste your cronjob with right-click and press `ESC` and then write `:wq`

This is only for unix-based machines. Windows doesn't have cron.